# Python: separate matrix by column values

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, split

I have a matrix `A` with 3 columns that looks something like, but much larger:

```
[[10 15 1.0]
 [21 13 1.0]
 [9  14 0.0]
 [14 24 1.0]
 [21 31 0.0]
 ...]
```

I want to create two separate matrices: one that contains all of the data with the third column=0.0, and another with all the data with the third column=1.0. So essentially splitting the data by the values 0.0 or 1.0 in the third column.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using [Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/), first find the rows where the third column has your desired value, then  extract the rows using [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

**Demo**

```
>>> import numpy
>>> A = numpy.array([[1, 0, 1],
                     [2, 0, 1],
                     [3, 0, 0],
                     [4, 0, 0],
                     [5, 0, 0]])
>>> A1 = A[A[:, 2] == 1, :] # extract all rows with the third column 1
>>> A0 = A[A[:, 2] == 0, :] # extract all rows with the third column 0
>>> A0
array([[3, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [5, 0, 0]])
>>> A1
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a
array([[ 10.,  15.,   1.],
       [ 21.,  13.,   1.],
       [  9.,  14.,   0.],
       [ 14.,  24.,   1.],
       [ 21.,  31.,   0.]])
>>> a[np.where(a[:,-1])]
array([[ 10.,  15.,   1.],
       [ 21.,  13.,   1.],
       [ 14.,  24.,   1.]])
>>> a[np.where(~a[:,-1].astype(bool))]
array([[  9.,  14.,   0.],
       [ 21.,  31.,   0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we'd separate the matrix using list comprehensions, there's no need to import additional libraries. First, one matrix that contains all of the data with the third column is `0.0`:

```
[x for x in matrix if x[2] == 0.0]
```

And another matrix with all the data that relates to when the third column is `1.0`:

```
[x for x in matrix if x[2] == 1.0]
```

For example:

```
matrix = [[10, 15, 1.0],
          [21, 13, 1.0],
          [ 9, 14, 0.0],
          [14, 24, 1.0],
          [21, 31, 0.0]]

[x for x in matrix if x[2] == 0.0]
=> [[ 9, 14, 0.0],
    [21, 31, 0.0]]

[x for x in matrix if x[2] == 1.0]
=> [[10, 15, 1.0],
    [21, 13, 1.0],
    [14, 24, 1.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use np.hsplit(ary, indices_or_sections)